# Apache tiles 3.0 not rendering

Tags: apache-tiles

I'm working on a web app on netbeans with spring and I want to include apache Tiles3. And when the page is deployed, it is not rendering correctly and just shows the path of the files in plain text. Can anyone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

here is my Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<import resource="beans.xml" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolverJsp"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

here is my tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition" template="WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="index" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Strutsss" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="WEB-INF/index.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="test" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Strutsss" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp" />
</definition>
```

template.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" />
    </title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="headerTD">                  
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />             
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="menu">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <div id="body">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

Please change your resolver in

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">

            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Delete you current viewResolverJsp

and please try to change

```
value="WEB-INF/index.jsp" />
```

in

```
value="/WEB-INF/index.jsp" />
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: yes, one with the class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver, to set the prefix and suffix of the view path. And the another one with the class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver to the tiles. Is that wrong?

Comment: i think they are conflicting. Try to remove it and see

Comment: Well, I removed  the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver, but it stills giving me the same result.

Comment: It finally worked. I was missing the slash in value="/WEB-INF/index.jsp" />. Thank you!!